# Using OR operator in a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

How can I use OR in a Java regex? I tried the following, but it's returning `null` instead of the text.

```
Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("\\*+|#+ (.+?)");
Matcher matcher = reg.matcher("* kdkdk"); \\ "# aksdasd"
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex syntax for searching for `X` or `Y` is `(X|Y)`. The parentheses are required if you have anything else in the pattern. You were searching for one of these patterns:

> a literal `*` repeated one or more times

OR

> a literal `#` repeated one or more times, followed by a space, followed by one or more of any character, matching a minimum number of times

This pattern matches `*` using the first part of the OR, but since that subpattern defines no capture groups, `matcher.group(1)` will be null. If you printed `matcher.group(0)`, you would get `*` as the output.

If you want to capture the first character to the right of a space on a line that starts with either "*" or "#" repeated some number of times, followed by a space and at least one character, you probably want:

```
Pattern.compile("(?:\\*+|#+) (.+?)");
```

If you want everything to the right of the space, you want:

```
Pattern.compile("(?:\\*+|#+) (.+)");
```

Comment: Pattern.compile("(\\*+|#+) (.+?)"); returns the character * or #, not the text after it..

Comment: @Naren - Ah, yeah. Edited to make the first group a non-capture group. Or you could use my original suggestion and use `matcher.group(2)`

Comment: @Naren - When you put parentheses around the terms to limit the scope of the OR operator, it also makes it a capture group. You can either account for that by using `matcher.group(2)` or use `(?:X|Y)` as the pattern, as I showed in my edited version. (The syntax `(?:X)` matches `X` without creating a capture group.)